# Relative distance to prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_{n,1}$ be the next biggest prime for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $p_{n,2}$ the next biggest but one and so on. (e.g. $p_{4,1} = 5$, $p_{4,2} = 7$, ...)

Are there $n,m \in \mathbb{N}, n\neq m$ so that
$$p_{n,j}-n=p_{m,j}-m$$
for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Hard to imagine that such a pair exists

Comment: If we can prove the existence of such a pair, would the Twin Prime Conjecture (and all similar looking conjectures) be proven?

Comment: @player3236 We could at least prove that there is a positive integer $k$ such that $p+k$ is prime for infinite many primes $p$. And this is as far as I know, currently unknwon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are prime gaps of arbitrary size (e.g. $k!+2,...,k!+k$ are all composite). If there were such a pair $m,n$ it would mean that the pattern of prime gaps repeats with a period of $|m-n|$, so arbitrarily large prime gaps would not be possible.